# What does "[controller]" mean?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

For example, the route from the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-on-multiple-controllers):

```
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PetsController : MyControllerBase
```

What does `"[controller]"` mean? I cannot find the definition in the MSDN docs, so please send me the docs if you do know where they are or are better at googling than I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area),

`[controller]` is a token and it will be replaced with the value of the `controller` name from the action where route is defined.

So in this case,
it indicates route `/Pets/...`.

Comment: So, if I named the controller, `PetsControllerController`, the route would be `/PetsController/...`?

Comment: Yeah, that will be `/PetsController/...`.